# What exactly is heliodisplay?

Tags: optics, fluid-dynamics

So I am really curious about how [IO2 Solutions' heliodisplay](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliodisplay) works. I know it uses a controlled environment to project 2D or stereo 3D images to air but what exactly is that controlled environment?

I assume they are changing air's refractive index by modifying its pressure and temperature etc. but I am not sure. I also couldn't find the patent of the idea in the records so I don't know how to access its technical description.

Comment: Would really like to know why I got downvoted.

Comment: Possibly because a reader thought your proposed  theory was implausible or wrong. This is no reason to downvote though, IMO - you're asking a *question* and seeking knowledge, after all.